# Construct a topological embedding

Tags: general-topology

For an arbitrary discrete space X, construct a compact topological space Y and a topological embedding Y.

I am think about construct $X={0,1}$ equipped with the discrete topology. Topology on Y={∅,{0,1},{1}} which is the Sierpinski space. Thus Y is immediately compact. I try to define the map as $f(∅)=∅， f(X)=X, f({0})=f({1})={1}$. Then the $ab:X->f(X)$ is homeomorphism. Would anyone help me to check if my idea is correct?

Comment: Taking $\{0,1\}$ is far from arbitrary. Also $Y$ is the set $\{0,1\}$ or the set $\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$? The latter is **not** the Sierpinski space. Finally embeddings are injective by definition.

Comment: There are standard constructions to do this. However, this looks like an exercise, and without context no-one can say what an appropriate answer is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is finite, $X$ is already compact, and you might as well let $Y=X$ with the identity map as your embedding. There’s no reason to add an extra point.

The exercise becomes interesting only when $X$ is infinite, and then adding another point is necessary. There is a way to do it by adding just one point: it’s called the [Alexandrov one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_%28mathematics%29#Alexandroff_one-point_compactification) of $X$. See if you can work it out from that little article; if you get stuck, feel free to leave a question for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is not correct, since $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$, $f(X)=X$, $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ does not define a function from $X$ to $Y$, let alone an injective one.